# python is buffering it's stdout in aws eks

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am running a python script inside a pod container in aws eks (managed kubernetes service). My script is something like following:

```
from model import startRunner
import time
while 1:
    startRunner()
    time.sleep(3600)
    print("waited for 1 hour", flush=True)
```

I only get the logs if the process crashes. If I run without loop, I only get the logs when it crashes or exited. My expectation was to flush the log as it runs, not buffering it.

I have also added environment variable into the pod as below (true is string though, as I haven't found as way to cast to boolean in manifest of kubernetes configmap):

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED : true
```

Also, as I am running script with conda, I have the following command to run the script:

```
CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "pymc3_env", "python", "-u", "sqs-poll.py"]
```

In the above command I have used `-u` to unbuffer the logs, however, it is still buffering.

Feels like, I am out of tricks. I am a newby in python and using python 3.5 or above to run the script. If anyone can help me to resolve this, that would be amazing. Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: `flush=True` should prevent Python from buffering the output. Something else must be buffering external to Python.

Comment: @Barmar anything to do with aws eks?  I doubt it, because it even buffers when I run it locally with docker container. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: It's possible, I'm not really familiar with Kubernetes.

Answer (score -1):

Try dumping the value of `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` in your script using something like

```py
import os

print(os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"])
```

If your script errors saying something like "missing key" then you haven't passed that value to your pod properly.

Here's a snipped from my own deployment which also runs a python script:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    ...
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-deployment
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-pull-secrets
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: {{ .Values.deployment.image }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        ...
        - name: PYTHONUNBUFFERED
          value: "1"
        ...
```